# HAProxy - URL redirection & rewriting

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, haproxy, redirect

I am completely new to haproxy setup. I want to setup haproxy on top of tomcat servers.

The below configuration works well for tomcat applications.

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1   local0
    log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
    maxconn 4096
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults

    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 20000
    contimeout      5000
    clitimeout      50000
    srvtimeout      50000

listen webfarm 100.100.100.100:80
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats uri /haproxy?statis
   stats realm Haproxy\ Auth
   stats auth user:password
   balance leastconn
   cookie JSESSIONID insert indirect nocache
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor
   server web01 192.168.1.1:8080 cookie A check
   server web02 192.168.1.2:8080 cookie B check
```

But i dont want user to enter the complete url. so when a user hits web1.example.com it need to server application from a tomcat webapp directory. Also i dont want the url changed.

```
Example : http://web1.example.com -> http://192.168.1.1:8080/applications/web1 & http://192.168.1.2:8080/applications/web1
```

Is this possible with a url redirection and url rewriting? If yes please help me with a sample configuration.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ugly, you should not do that, it causes all sort of issues with redirects, referrers and base URLs for static objects. It's trivial to do with reqrep (to rewrite the request) and rsprep (to rewrite the location), but you'd better switch to a more clever idea than break your site on purpose and then complain all the time that you constantly have broken links in the HTML code etc... In short, **don't do this!**

Comment: Currently i am using Apache Proxy balancer to do all this but bit annoyed with broken pipe issues. So thought of trying it out with HAProxy. But yeah you brought up good points. I am dropping this idea for now.

Thanks.