# Web application url redirect using Apache or haproxy

Tags: java, apache, url-rewriting, webserver, haproxy

We have a Java web application with multiple services using http. It's accessible via abc.com ,  Currently reverse proxy and headers are passed through Apache or haproxy. I have tried with rewrite rule / condition on Apache, I was successful in accessing webapp on xyz.com but some functionalities like search are failing as they are using abc.com. We have many CORS, cookies and X headers like X-forwarded-host for switching between services. Is it possible to write successful rewrites on Apache or haproxy which does the needful.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can provide your rewrite code?

Comment: In Apache conf I added Rewrite Cond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com  Rewrite Rule ^(.*) http:// xyx com/$1 [P]. I have tried changing to https_host also. thanks for reply. Ignore those spaces in between.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39623199/redirect-to-new-domain-from-an-existing-domain-apache-haproxy?rq=1 ?

Comment: Here is another interesting issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013098/haproxy-url-redirection-rewriting?rq=1 . . . so with a bit search here I think you'll find what you need, there are several questions related to your problem.